# Domain logic separation with IdentityServer

Tags: identityserver4

We have MVC application with role membership and IdentityServer for SSO, both are separated applications. We have two roles in our application - Admin and RegularUser. Each of them has a specific set of properties, for example:

```
public class Admin
{
    public string Area { get; set; }

    public int Code { get; set;}
}

public class RegularUser
{
    public string SkypeId { get; set; }

    public string HomeAddress { get; set; }
}
```

According to [IdentityServer template](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Templates/blob/master/src/IdentityServer4AspNetIdentity/Models/ApplicationUser.cs) we should use single ApplicationUser class to store all profile data. What is the best practice of organization role-specific data storage across multiple applications? My thought is to separate profile storage (ApplicationUser, in scope of IdentityServer) from domain entities (Admin and RegularUser, in scope of MVC application) and link them together with a key:

```
public class Admin
{
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }

    public string Area { get; set; }

    public int Code { get; set;}
}

public class RegularUser
{
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }

    public string SkypeId { get; set; }

    public string HomeAddress { get; set; }
}
```

When we redirect from SSO after successful login to MVC application we can fetch Admin or RegularUser in controller like this:

```
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> SomeAction()
{
    string userId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);

    if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
        Admin admin = await _adminRepository.GetByApplicationUserId(userId);
        /* logic for admin */
    }

    if (User.IsInRole("RegularUser"))
    {
        RegularUser regularUser = await _regularUserRepository.GetByApplicationUserId(userId);
        /* logic for regularUser */
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use IdentityServer for authorization too.

1. Define an IdentityResource for each application and some UserClaimTypes for it.

   `new IdentityResource("app1_permissions", new string[] { "permission_in_app1" });`
2. Fill *permission_in_app1* claim with user's permissions in app1.

   `new Claim("permission_in_app1","[read1,write2]")`
3. In your client, request *app1_permissions* scope from IdentityServer when you are redirecting user.

   `scope: app1_permissions openid profile`

Each user has a collection of claims which user1 has different information as user2.

> A claim is a statement about a subject by an issuer. Claims represent attributes of the subject that are useful in the context of authentication and authorization operations.

Using claim-based identity, we can store different information about each user.

[Claim Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claim?view=netframework-4.8#remarks)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this not I was asking for. I dont know how to store different profile data in one ApplicationUser class.

Comment: Thank you! Your suggestion to use claims to store role specific info seems to me a little bit strange mainly because of this info do not used in context authentication or authorization process. Also all claims are stored inside jwt token and size of this token seems citical for me.

Comment: Your welcome, user claims wont be included in jwt token. don't worry about token size.

Comment: According to https://jwt.io/introduction/ claims are stored in payload part of the token

Comment: Of course jwt.io is right, but IdentityServer has some configuration which allows you to select which claims you want to be included in the token. When you're doing Client configuration, you can set *AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken* to true, which cause your jwt token include all the user's claims. By default it is false.

Comment: Did not know about this feature. May be I misunderstand something. How can I obtain this claims inside my MVC application?

Comment: In your startup.cs configuration, there is property which load UserInfo after authentication. for more information look at (User Authentication and Identity with Angular, Asp.Net Core and IdentityServer)[https://fullstackmark.com/post/21/user-authentication-and-identity-with-angular-aspnet-core-and-identityserver]